# What are the good practices to optimize computation in Pandas when having several specifications?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, apply

I often encounter a problem when I am doing queries with lots of specification, **How to speed up the process?**

Basically I really often use the `apply` function to get a result but quite often, the computation takes a **long time**.

Is there a **good practice** to find how to optimize the Pandas code?

Here is an example, I have a DataFrame representing the exchange of a chat containing 3 columns:

- `timestamp`: the timestamp of the message
- `sender_id`: the id of the sender
- `receiver_id`: the id of the receiver

The goal is to find the fraction of messages that had a response in less than 5 minutes. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

size_df = 30000
np.random.seed(42)

data = {
    'timestamp': pd.date_range('2019-03-01', periods=size_df, freq='30S').astype(int),
    'sender_id': np.random.randint(5, size=size_df),
    'receiver_id': np.random.randint(5, size=size_df)
}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is how the DataFrame looks like:

```
print(dataframe.head().to_string())
              timestamp  sender_id  receiver_id
0   1551398400000000000          4            2
1   1551398430000000000          3            2
2   1551398460000000000          1            1
3   1551398490000000000          4            3
4   1551398520000000000          4            3
```

The function used by apply:

```
def apply_find_next_answer_within_5_min(row):
    """
        Find the index of the next response in a range of 5 minutes
    """
    [timestamp, sender, receiver] = row
    ## find the next responses from receiver to sender in the next 5 minutes 
    next_responses = df_groups.get_group((receiver, sender))["timestamp"]\
                        .loc[lambda x: (x > timestamp) & (x < timestamp + 5 * 60 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000)]
    ## if there is no next responses just return NaN
    if not next_responses.size:
        return np.nan
    ## find the next messages from sender to receiver in the next 5 minutes 
    next_messages = df_groups.get_group((sender, receiver))["timestamp"]\
            .loc[lambda x: (x > timestamp) & (x < timestamp + 5 * 60 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000)]

    ## if the first next message is before next response return nan else return index next reponse
    return np.nan if next_messages.size and next_messages.iloc[0] < next_responses.iloc[0] else next_responses.index[0]

%%timeit
df_messages = dataframe.copy()
## create a dataframe to easily find messages from a specific sender and receiver, speed up the querying process for these messages.
df_groups = df_messages.groupby(["sender_id", "receiver_id"])
df_messages["next_message"] = df_messages.apply(lambda row: apply_find_next_answer_within_5_min(row), axis=1)
```

Output `timeit`:

```
42 s ± 2.16 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So it takes `42 seconds` to apply the function for a `30 000 rows` DataFrame. I think it is **very long**, but I don't find a way to make it more efficient. I already gained `40 seconds` by using the intermediate dataframe that groups the sender and receiver instead of querying the big dataframe in the apply function.

This would the response of this specific problem:

```
1 - df_messages.next_message[lambda x: pd.isnull(x)].size / df_messages.next_message.size
0.2753
```

So in such scenarios, how do you find a way to compute more efficiently? Are there some tricks to think about?

In this example, I don't believe it is possible to use vectorizations all the way but maybe by using more groups, it is possible to go quicker?

Comment: can in the real case sender_id and receiver_id the same, as in your example?

Comment: @Ben.T: Well it is your call I would say, it depends if you imagine a chat where you can talk to yourself or not, but it is note rare to see chats with the possibily to talk to yourself: messenger, whatsapp, SMS, ... But it won't be interesting to use this data to find responses to the next message of yourself so it might be safe to assume that these messages has been filtered. It is not a real case that I encountered so this is why I don't have a fixed idea on this :).

Comment: About the method you're trying to apply: it finds the index of the next message which occurs within the next five minutes?

Comment: @ifly6: it finds the next message that the receiver sent to the sender of the current row within the five minutes. I returned the index because I thought it was convenient and would be interesting in a real use case but the value returned is just meant in this case to be used as a mask to know what fractions of messages received an answer in lass than 5 minutes. I also considered that if the sender sent a new message before receiving an answer, I would consider that the message received no answer.

Comment: `apply_next_answer_within_5_min` -> `apply_find_next_answer_within_5_min` just for reference. This is an interesting question, I'll take a look at it when I get off work

Comment: @ifly6 thank you, I edited the question :). I think that Ben.T's answer is really great, basically, it just tells me that I really need to learn how to properly use GroupBy, I have the sense that we can do pretty much everything using it, but I don't have the intuition on how it works yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to group your dataframe

```
groups = dataframe.reset_index()\ #I reset_index for later to get the value
                  .groupby([ frozenset([se, re]) #need frosenset to allow the groupby
                             for se, re in dataframe[['sender_id', 'receiver_id']].values])
```

Now you can create boolean mask meeting your condition

```
mask_1 = (  # within a group, check if the following message is sent from the other one
            (groups.sender_id.diff(-1).ne(0) 
            # or if the person talks to oneself 
            | dataframe.sender_id.eq(dataframe.receiver_id) ) 
            # and check if the following message is within 5 min
            & groups.timestamp.diff(-1).gt(-5*60*1000*1000*1000))
```

Now create the column with the index you look for with the mask and shift on the index:

```
df_messages.loc[mask_1, 'next_message'] = groups['index'].shift(-1)[mask_1]
```

and you get like with your method and should be faster:

```
print (df_messages.head(20))
              timestamp  sender_id  receiver_id  next_message
0   1551398400000000000          3            1           NaN
1   1551398430000000000          4            1           NaN
2   1551398460000000000          2            3           NaN
3   1551398490000000000          4            1           NaN
4   1551398520000000000          4            3           NaN
5   1551398550000000000          1            1           NaN
6   1551398580000000000          2            3          10.0
7   1551398610000000000          2            4           NaN
8   1551398640000000000          2            4           NaN
9   1551398670000000000          4            1           NaN
10  1551398700000000000          3            2           NaN
11  1551398730000000000          2            4           NaN
12  1551398760000000000          4            0          18.0
13  1551398790000000000          1            0           NaN
14  1551398820000000000          3            3          16.0
15  1551398850000000000          1            2           NaN
16  1551398880000000000          3            3           NaN
17  1551398910000000000          4            1           NaN
18  1551398940000000000          0            4           NaN
19  1551398970000000000          3            2           NaN
```

Comment: How is `mask_1` invoked on the groups?

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is impressive: `76.6 ms ± 4.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`. I think that the condition `groups.sender_id.diff(-1).ne(0)` forces the sender to be different to the receiver so I would need to work on the conditions to have the same output :). I don't really understand how the groupby works, I get that you create a set on every row based on the sender and receiver but how Pandas actually groups the values afterwards ?

Comment: @SmileyProd actually I already added the condition about sender being the same as receiver with `| dataframe.sender_id.eq(dataframe.receiver_id)` as you said in a comment it may happen :) the groupby works such as all the operations (here diff or later shift but any operation is possible) are performed per group. This allows to compare conversation between two ids

Comment: @ifly6 actually with the construction of mask_1, there is already the groups took into account while the mask can be used on the whole dataframe

Comment: @Ben.T sorry my question was unclear. I do understand that the operations are performed per group, but when I usually use `groupby`, I feed it with the name of the columns on which I want to perform the groupby. Here you fed the `groupby` a list of sets. Is it because the size of the list is the same as the index, so that `groupby` can get the index to feed each group ?

Comment: @SmileyProd sorry, yes it is because the length of the list is the same as the number of rows, then you get all the rows group where the set is the same :) I'm not sure if it is working through index but I guess you can see it this way. Just to be sure, the `reset_index` I used at first is to be able to do `groups['index'].shift5...`, otherwise it would have been difficult to get the original index for this specific operation. It was not necessary by itself to create the mask!